# Reading a JSON structure in Javascript

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, json, parser

I am trying to read this json string in Javascript so that I can access its node. However I get undefined.

```
const jsonStr = '{"data":"{\"page\":\"1\",\"firstName\":\"c\",\"company\":\"\",\"reqValidation\":false,\"notes\":\"\",\"roles\":[],\"level\":\"beginner\"}"}';
```

I am trying to read the data in JS using :

`jsonStr.data or jsonStr.['data']` gives me `undefined`.

I tried to use `JSON.parser(jsonStr);`, I get :

```
   Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token p in JSON at position 11
        at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
```

The JSON is produced using below. The data part is what I am trying to read in another JS file.

```
 const data = JSON.stringify({
            page: "1", firstName: this.firstName, lastName: this.lastName, company: this.company, reqValidation: isValid,
            notes: this.notes, roles: this.roles
        });
        const nextEvnt = new CustomEvent('initiate', {
            detail: { data }
        });
        this.dispatchEvent(nextEvnt);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data can be passed through as an object, so no need to stringify. Your main problem is this:

```
{ data }
```

This creates a new object with an attribute `data` with the contents stringified (again). This double-encoding is what's causing you grief. Instead:

```
    const nextEvnt = new CustomEvent('initiate', {
        detail: data
    });
```

Or, even better, just use the original object:

```
const nextEvnt = new CustomEvent('initiate', {
  detail: {
        page: "1", firstName: this.firstName, lastName: this.lastName, company: this.company, reqValidation: isValid,
        notes: this.notes, roles: this.roles
    } });
```

Here's a quick demonstration of how the object notation screws things up:

```
var x = { a: 5, b: 10 }
var y = JSON.stringify(x); // { "a": 5, "b": 10 }
var z = JSON.stringify({x}); // { "x": { "a": 5, "b": 10 } }
```

Comment: Thank you!! I got this json now: const var = {"page":"1","firstName":"j","lastName":"k","company":"","reqValidation":true,"notes":"","roles":[],"level":"beginner","file":""} . When I try to access a JSON key like - var['page'] var.page , it gives me undefined.

Comment: @SfdcBat You shouldn't have any JSON, it should be an object? I think your problem might be elsewhere.

Comment: @SfdcBat In your event handler, `event.detail.page` for example, should return `"1"`.

Answer (score 1):

`jsonStr` is a json. And `data` inside is also json. Thus

```
'{"data":"{\"page\":\"1\",\"firstName\":\"c\",\"company\":\"\",\"reqValidation\":false,\"notes\":\"\",\"roles\":[],\"level\":\"beginner\"}"}';
```

is basically escapped json. You have to unescape it.

```
const jsonStr = unescape('{"data":"{\"page\":\"1\",\"firstName\":\"c\",\"company\":\"\",\"reqValidation\":false,\"notes\":\"\",\"roles\":[],\"level\":\"beginner\"}"}');
```

Playground link  : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/JCjU-jCmd/1/edit

Comment: There's no need to unescape it... just fix the source of the problem.

Comment: @sfdcfox agreed I guess, I just jumped on the gun